# Find the eigenvalues of linear transformation $T(x)= x - 2 \frac{x.v}{v.v} v$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$  be a  nonzero vector .

Define  a  linear transformation

$$T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3  \ \ \  \text{by} \ \ \ T(x)= x - 2 \frac{x.v}{v.v} v$$

where $x.y $ denotes the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Find the eigenvalues  of $T ?$

My attempt : I take ordered  basis  $e_1=(1,0,0) , e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$

since $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$  is a  nonzero vector so i take $v=(1,0,0)$

Now $T(e_1)=e_1-2\frac{(e_1.v)}{||v||}v=(1,0,0)-2(1,0,0)=(-1,0,0)$

$T(e_2)=(0,1,0)-2=(0,1,0)$

$T(e_3)=(0,0,1)$

Now matrix of $T$  is $\begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0\\0&1&0 \\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

Therefore the  eigenvalue  of $T$ are $-1$ and $1$

Is it true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your eigenvalues are correct, but your reasoning is still wrong. You can't just define $v$, it is supposed to be arbitrary

ust find the eigenspaces: One is $\mathrm{span}({v})$: Just plug in $v$:
$$
T(v) = v - 2v = -v.
$$
So $v$ has eigenvalue $-1$.

The other one is $\mathrm{span}(v)^\perp$: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x.v = 0$. So
$$
T(x) = x.
$$
So all vectors in $\mathrm{span}(v)$ have eigenvalue 1. $\mathrm{span}(v)^\perp$ has dimension 2.

Operators like yours are called Householder transformations.

Comment: You could have added a geometrical understanding of Householder transformations which are plainly  orthogonal symmetries with respect to a plane (more generally a hyperplane) with normal vector $v$ explaining at once that $v$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $-1$ (because $T(v)=-v$), and that the eigenspace associated to eigenvalue $1$ is 2-dimensional : it is naturally this plane whose elements $u$ are invariant ($T(u)=u$)

Comment: You are right. Thank you

Comment: @Meowdog can you please elaborate a little bit the concept you used here "One is span (v)"?

Comment: The eigenspace to one eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the linear space of eigenvectors that belong to $\lambda$.  $\mathrm{span}(v) = \mathbb{R}v$ is the space with all eigenvectors that belong to the eigenvalue $-1$. Eigenspaces are always linear spaces.